# CodeIgniter : Transaction ERROR vs MySQL ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

How can I tell if the transaction was FALSE or if something else happened(locked table)?

```
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->where('id', $id)
             ->limit(1);

    $q = $this->db->delete('table');

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $this->db->trans_status() ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

For example, the transaction might fail because of a foreign key constraint. If that is the case I would run another query. In any other case I want to retry the original query.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the query was succesfull

```
if($q)
 echo ok 
else
 echo ko
```